Could Time-Dilation-Accelerated Decay Near a Black Hole's Singularity Resolve the Information Paradox?
I'm an extremely amateur physics enthusiast with a conceptual idea about black hole evaporation that I'd like to get some feedback on. I'm particularly interested in whether this idea is internally coherent or coherent at all and if it has any potential to address the information paradox. I want to emphasize that I'm not a physicist and my understanding of these topics is limited. I've used AI tools to help me express my ideas more clearly and concisely, but the core concept is my own.
The Idea:
The core concept is that extreme time dilation near the singularity could significantly accelerate the decay of matter, possibly even causing protons to decay if they are fundamentally unstable (as suggested by some Grand Unified Theories, or GUTs). This process would be driven by the immense gravitational time dilation as matter approaches the position where gravity tends to infinity.
The process would unfold as follows:
Matter falling into a black hole is spaghettified into a stream of atoms.
As this stream approaches the singularity, time dilation becomes extreme. From the perspective of each atom, the black hole's entire future lifetime would pass almost instantaneously as it approaches (but never reaches) the point in space where gravity is at its maximum.
This extreme time dilation could accelerate the decay of all matter, including hydrogen, converting it into radiation (I'm calling this "Guilherme radiation" just as a placeholder, after myself).
This decay would happen sequentially, atom by atom, as the matter approaches the position where gravity tends to infinity thus time distortion to giving infinite time to decay.
As a result, matter might never reach the singularity in its classical form, potentially avoiding the formation of a singularity altogether.
As the black hole evaporates via Hawking radiation and its gravity weakens, there would be a point where the remaining energy that decayed from process is released in a final burst as the gravity cannot hold the radiation any longer.
The information content of the infalling matter could potentially be encoded in the outgoing radiation, including this final burst, offering a possible resolution to the information paradox.
My Question:
Is this a coherent idea from the perspective of established physics? Could such a mechanism, driven by time-dilation-accelerated decay, potentially play a role in black hole evaporation and the resolution of the information paradox?
I'm aware that this is a speculative concept, and I fully expect there to be flaws or inconsistencies. I'm very open to criticism and feedback, especially regarding potential flaws, inconsistencies with known physics, or any aspects that are simply not viable. I'm also interested in how this idea relates to other proposed solutions to the information paradox, such as those involving non-violent nonlocality, firewalls, or fuzzballs. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated! I know this post might seem like a joke from an actually knowledgeable point of view and i am sorry for that in anticipation.

Non-mainstream physics and personal theories are off topic here.

Sorry about that, was reading the FAQ after the post, where could be a better place to post this?

Although Guilherme is asking about a speculative time-dilation effect, he has repeatedly stated that he wants to know what mainstream physics says about this. He is not proposing a non-mainstream theory.

I don't think it's that far off of course and PM 2Ring is right, but I feel it should be edited to be more clear on your (mis)understanding of how time dilation works for matter that is falling into a black hole compared to the black holes lifetime.

The problem is that for any matter falling into the black hole time flows at its normal rate, and the matter passes through the event horizon in a finite time. Indeed for a solar mass black hole the time taken to fall from a few Schwarzschild radii through the horizon is of the order of milliseconds. That means the matter doesn't have time to decay.
It is true that we observers far from the black hole see the clocks of infalling observers to be running slowly, but this means that from our perspective the decay rate of the infalling matter slows down as well. Although we observe infalling matter to take an infinite time to cross the horizon the decay rate of the matter slows to zero. The end result is that in both the infalling matter's frame and our frame the matter never decays.

Assuming i understood it, what if then it doesn't decay instead? And by the time some of the matter is reaching the point where there would be singularity the blackhole already would have evaporated sufficiently and thus it would be allowed to escape as mere matter on the end?

@Guilhermesampaiodeoliveira The time to reach the singularity from the edge of the event horizon of a black hole of $n$ solar masses is about $ n(1.55 \times 10^{-5} )$ seconds in the frame of the infalling observer. This is much shorter than the lifetime of said black hole. A black hole just the mass of the sun itself has a lifetime longer than the current age of the universe by many orders of magnitude.

Yes, but i am considering the effects of time dilation and supposing it grows exponentially as we fall further into the black hole from the perspective of the object, so suppose that in a black hole with n=3.3 it would take  5.115 * 10^-5 seconds to fall, and the black hole lasts 3.5937 * 10^68 however because of the Lorentz factor from the perspective of the object as it approaches the singularity at some point time outside the blackhole passes ~ 10^72 times faster and the blackhole evaporates before matter reaches the center, never forming the singularity.

@Guilhermesampaiodeoliveira A black hole evaporates before a falling object reaches the horizon, but the object itself still evaporates as well. Evaporating black holes don’t have a singularity.

Wait, there are non evaporating black holes?

Well it seems i might have gottem at least one aspect right? For Evaporating ones at least?
